# Linode VPS storage space full, site down, unable to stay logged in

Tags: networking, memory, troubleshooting, webserver

I am using Linode Server. After login I can see Storage space is full. Because of this full storage our website is down. I can't even log in with SSH using Putty. If I reboot the server then I can access it via SSH for only 5 minutes; after that, SSH stops working.

Can any one explain how to fix this issue?

[image: Click here to see Screen shot]

Comment: 1. Reboot, 2. Quickly get SSH access, 3. Use a tool to see whats filling the disk. 4. reboot if needed 5. kill the service creating those files. Easy.

Comment: Thanks.  

I reboot many time.  after rebooting server is working only 4-5min  then again same problem.  Can you tell me any tool name?